# Why not pop-up window when I using SwingTrayIcon

Tags: java, spring, swing, java-8, jframe

I have a problem that the windows cannot pop-up window which setting on the timer. The code below the Block. How can I resolve the problem? Can someone tell me. I very much appreciate it.

1. I want to get my fortunes to show on the poping window.
2. When I try this code first, It seems successful, But once. I had never change the code, but it does not work.
3. I am trying to restart my computer, and I had twice but failed too.
4. My computer is a system of Windows 10 X64

```
package systemTray;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 * This program demonstrates the system tray API.
 * @version 1.02 2016-05-10
 * @author Cay Horstmann
 */
public class SystemTrayTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      SystemTrayApp app = new SystemTrayApp();
      app.init();
   }
}

class SystemTrayApp
{
   public void init()
   {      
      final TrayIcon trayIcon;

      if (!SystemTray.isSupported())
      {
         System.err.println("System tray is not supported.");
         return;
      }

      SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
      Image image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("cookie.png")).getImage();

      PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
      MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem("Exit");
      exitItem.addActionListener(event -> System.exit(0));
      popup.add(exitItem);

      trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Your Fortune", popup);

      trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
      trayIcon.addActionListener(event ->
         {
            trayIcon.displayMessage("How do I turn this off?",
                  "Right-click on the fortune cookie and select Exit.",
                  TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
         });

      try
      {
         tray.add(trayIcon);
      }
      catch (AWTException e)
      {
         System.err.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
         return;
      }
      //get fortunes to show 
      final List<String> fortunes = readFortunes();
      // I want to pop up window to show message with the timer.
      Timer timer = new Timer(10000, event ->
         {
            int index = (int) (fortunes.size() * Math.random());
            trayIcon.displayMessage("Your Fortune", fortunes.get(index),
                  TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
         });
      timer.start();
   }
}
```

Comment: I don’t have a Windows machine on hand with which to test this, but I suspect your program is exiting immediately.  Try adding a long Thread.sleep to your `main` method.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have a try with a long Thread.sleep to the main method, But It has the same result.

Comment: Works for me. But recent Windows 10 doesn’t display it as a message at the tray icon, but rather in the message center. There, you can configure message of particular applications to be shown or not. Since to Windows, all Java applications started with the standard launcher look like a single application (java.exe or javaw.exe), it might be the case that you (or someone else) had turned messages off when a different Java application displayed a message.